# Named Cells and Formulas In Excel

Tags: vba, excel

How do I utilize named cell references in Excel that aren't absolute.  I want to be able to take a formula and be able to drag it across excel and have one name cell reference update to a different named cell as I move across.

[image]

For example:  I want to keep RevenuePerStay going across the formulas row and have excel updated the cell reference to the number of people staying.  So

```
400 should be RevenuePerStay * Stay400

600 should be `RevenuePerStay * Stay600`
```

I tried using mixed cell reference and relative cell references using the dollar sign but excel will not accept this.

Comment: Not quite what you ask, but if you use a `Table` and structured references, in which case the Name = column header, then the Name will actually change as you drag the formula to the right.  If your formula is outside the table, when you get past the last column name, it will wrap around back to the first.  So be careful.

Comment: As of now this is beyond my level in excel but it is good to know options exists for approaching this problem in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your stays are in row 5:

For this worksheet, click on cell C7 and go to create a new named range called Stays and for the formula write =C$5$ and exit the name manager.

Now change your formula in C7 to being RevenuePerStay*Stays and drag it across. This will get the right amount of stays you want each time.

In explicit answer to your question: no you would never get the name in the formula to change unless you put all scenarios in the formula using multiple if statements.

Comment: I need the formula view to show C7 as being RevenuePerStay * Stay200 not RevenuePerStay * Stays.  It appears entering the formula manually for each cells works as was subtly suggested in your explicit answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If I understand your question correctly, this method seems convoluted because you can use `=RevenuePerStay*C5` and drag over the row, and it should give the answer you want.

If you really want to take the advantage of `named range` and make it change dynamically, you will need to incorporate with `INDIRECT` like this:

```
=RevenuePerStay*INDIRECT("Stay"&C5)
```

But this is assuming you have all the `named ranges` defined properly such as `Stay200, Stay400, Stay600, Stay800, Stay1000` like below.  Otherwise it will not work.

[image]

Comment: This method allows the user to drag the formula across the row if needed but when I check formula view I still don't have the proper cell Name of Stays200, Stays400, Stays600, etc, etc as being used in the formula box.

Comment: It basically doesn't do that way as far as I know.  You can't drag the formula through cells to pop `named range` inside your formula.  Maybe I didn't explain this clearly in the answer.  Not sure the purpose of what you are trying to do here, but use `=RevenuePerStay*C5` should give you the results although you still can't see the `named range` either.